# While in a for loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to know the number of zeros which first appear in a list, before any other number.

For example:
`L1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]` - the output should be 5, which is the number of zeros.
`L2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]` - the output should be zero. Although there are 5 zeros in this list but the list starts with 1.

Here is my code:

```
k = 0
for i in L1:
    while i == 0:
        k = k + 1
```

It doesn't work though. I think it is an infinite loop, but I don't know why.

Comment: Your while-loop only terminates when `i` is not 0. Can you see what happens during the first iteration of the while-loop? How about the second iteration? Perhaps you meant to use and if-statement rather than a while-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of what will happen the first time `i` gets set to `0`.

The `while` loop will start and *never* stop, because `i` is not changed within that loop.

You would be better off with something as per the following transcript, a slight modification of yours:

```
>>> list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
>>> count = 0
>>> for item in list1:
...     if item == 0:
...         count = count + 1
...     else:
...         break
... 
>>> print count
5
```

or the slightly shorter variation which breaks immediately for a non-zero value, adding one otherwise.:

```
>>> list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2]
>>> count = 0
>>> for item in list1:
...     if item != 0: break
...     count = count + 1
... 
>>> print count
5
```

Comment: Also, if it wasn't `0` to begin with, it won't execute at all.

Comment: @Dennis, that case is fine since `k` ends up at 0, which is correct.

Comment: The `else: break` in here is a mistake, because it breaks out of the for loop.  So, if you have any zeroes after a non-zero number, they won't get counted.  Removing `else: break` makes this example work.

Comment: This is actually what the original poster wanted.

Comment: @Mark, that was what the question called for. It wants the number of _leading_ zeroes, not the count of zeroes in the whole list. The `L2` example makes that clear.

Comment: Whoops, thanks paxdiablo, I absolutely misread the question (multiple times!)

Answer (score 2):

As other commentators have said, the problem in your code is that you seem to misunderstand the meaning of the `while` keyword. That aside, for problems like these, I often prefer a more functional style:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> k = len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == 0, L1)))
>>> k
5
>>> k = len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x == 0, L2)))
>>> k
0
```

If you are just beginning to get to know Python, playing around with what the `itertools` offers is well worth it.

Comment: I would use `sum(1 for _ in takewhile(...))` instead.

Comment: I kind of wish there was some sort of `iterlen`, but the `sum` trick works pretty well. (It always feels kind of weird to think that I've written code where that actually matters.)

Answer (score 0):

My answer expands on paxdiablo's.  Thanks to him for clarifying OP's intent with the L2 case, which I had misread.

While `itertools` is handy for this kind of thing, at the point you're at, I'd say mastering the basic language features is worthwhile.

In your code, you do this:

```
L1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2]

k = 0
for i in L1:
    while i == 0:
        k = k + 1
```

When you run that chunk of code on `L1`, it loops forever. Here's why:

`for` causes the code that's enclosed (meaning the code below that's set aside by indentation) to loop.  So, your `for i in L1:` loop runs everything indented below it once for each thing in L1.

But, `while` does something similar.  `while` tells Python to run the indented code below it over and over until the condition on the `while` statement is `False`.

So, in the case of `L1`, the first time through the `for` loop, `i` gets set to 0.  Then, `while i == 0:` says to execute the code enclosed, `k = k + 1`, over and over again until `i` is no longer zero.  Unfortunately, since the code in the `while` loop does not change the value of `i`, `i` will be zero until the end of time, so it runs forever, repeatedly adding one to `k`.

What you're looking for is an `if` statement, which will not loop.  It will just run the enclosed code, or not, based on whether its test is true.  So, instead of:

```
    while i == 0:
        k = k + 1
```

you can use

```
    if i == 0:
        k = k + 1
    else:
        break
```

Then, each time through the `for` loop, the code asks whether `i` is zero, and if so, *only once*, it adds one to `k`, then goes on to the next list element. To cover your L2 case, if you hit a number that is not zero, `break` exits the `for` loop and stops counting.

The answer presented with `itertools` is clever, useful, good to know, and probably what you'd want to use for very large lists, but since it appears you're just learning the language (and probably learning your first language), it's worth learning how to use `for`, `while`, and `if` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking while does, is carry on as normal until the condition isn't met. What it really does, is repeat the code inside of the while as a loop until the condition isn't met.

Here's my solution, which tries to work as similarly to yours as possible, by carrying on counting until the number isn't a 0 then looking at how far it's come and breaking out of the for loop.

```
k = 0
for index,item in enumerate(L1):
    if item != 0:
        k = len(L1[:index])
        break
```